# Ubuntu Doesnt start after password

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, simplecv, ubuntu-13.10

I installed the new ubuntu 13 on my laptop(Dell N5110). After that i used the sudo commands for updating and upgrading it. I was prompted to restart the computer. But before restarting i installed the simplecv from the following tutorialthrough github.

http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/install-opencv-2-3-1-and-simplecv-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-arch-linux/

When i restarted the computer i got a blank screen after putting the password. I searched the net but i couldn't find the relavent answer. Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes my ubuntu doen't  start up correctly. I discovered, though, that I can just press the enter key a few times if anything gets stuck. This sounds weird, I know, but it's worth a shot.